# handling data retrieval latency angular

Tags: angular, http, observable, latency, subscribe

First off haven't coded in over a decade (former Java developer), so just getting familiar with Angular 4 as a hobby, but there is a basic understanding I'm lacking. I searched for handling data retrieval latency with observables, but did not come back any relevant results. Hope someone here can help and explain. It revolves around the following TypeScript code (see inline comments too):

**RemoteDataService**

```
export class RemoteDataService {
private headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
constructor(private http: Http) { }

 public getData(url)  {
  return this.http.get(url)
  .map(
    (response: Response) => {
      const data = response.json();
      return data;
    }
  )
 }
}
```

**ArticleService**

```
export class ArticleService implements OnInit {
_articles: Article[];

constructor(private _remoteDataService: RemoteDataService) {
  this.onGet();
  console.log(JSON.stringify(this._articles)) **//<- this._articles is null** 
  setTimeout(()=> console.log(JSON.stringify(this._articles + "////")), 3000) 
  } **//<- but if I wait 3 seconds this._articles is set to data elements**

 public onGet() {
   this._remoteDataService.getData('./assets/articles.json')
   .subscribe(
   (articles: any[]) => {
    this._articles = articles, 
    console.log(this._articles) **//<- this_.articles is set**
    },
    (error) => console.log(error))

    //console.log(this._articles) **//<- if I uncomment this_.articles is null, huh?**
  }
 }
```

Output:

> article.service.ts:34 "undefined////"
>
> article.service.ts:46 (20) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, ?>{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
>
> article.service.ts:35 "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object >Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object >Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object >Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object >Object],[object Object]////"

**My questions are**:

1) Why in the `onGet()` method does `this._articles` go from being set to null?

2) How is data latency usually handled, because my component calling the services is crashing because the articles have not been set yet?

Answer (score 0):

1) The call you are making to your service is happening **asynchronously** which means the call is made in another thread, but `onGet()` continues executing. this._articles is not set yet when you log it in the console.

2) Whew, that is a big question, and the answer depends largely on what you are trying to accomplish. For one, using setTimeout() is bad practice. You need to design your components in such a way that they can work without any data. If it is your template that is breaking, the [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths) might come in handy. If you provide more details I would be happy to help.

Comment: the setTimeout() function was for testing purposes only. I get the async thing, what I don't get is why it went from being set to null. (The last comment in the code)

Comment: It's because the code doesn't execute in the order that it's written. The subscribe function is called, but console.log is called immediately after, which is before the call is finished.

Comment: thanks, I get the whole instruction sequence thing, however I'm still not understanding why the console prints out this_.articles as a viable object, then immediately after prints out this._articles as null. It would seem to me that null would have been printed each time, then on the timeout the value would finally print. I have moved on, to a new problem now, but that is  still very fuzzy to me.

Comment: It will just take some getting used to. Just read a few articles and it will help. A side note: do as little in the component constructors as possible. You should do the work in ngOnInit() instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out . . . sorry to bother everyone.

I put this in my article service

```
articleHasChanged = new Subject<Article[]>();
```

this added this code to my component

```
  private _articleSubscription: Subscription;

this._articleSubscription = this._articleService.articleHasChanged.subscribe({
  next: (articles) => {
    console.log("Time to get the article");
    this._articleService.getArticleByID(this.id);
    console.log(this.diagnostic)
  }
}
)
```

This seems to work

Answer (score 0):

You need to read more about Angular subscriptions and observables. Because these work differently to how you think it works. This is probably a [good article for that](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-http-requests-with-observables) but you should search. I think this is the [official API documentation](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html)

This is very simple to understand. Whenever you make a request in your app. The app does not have to wait until the request finishes. This is very similar to how your browser works. You enter a url into your browser and do other things while the page loads then when you see that the browser has finished loading you resume and use through the page. When you use `this.http.get(url)` The browser handles the request outside your current app scope. So the following blocks of code will continue to be executed while the browser makes the requests and waits for the response. So when any other code is executed the request has not yet finished loading which happens very quickly while a request could take seconds to finish loading.

When you use `return this.http.get(url).map()` - you're returning an observable which is returned immediately after the request is called - when there has been no response from the server since it is still loading.

```
.subscribe(
   (articles: any[]) => {
    this._articles = articles, 
    console.log(this._articles) **//<- this_.articles is set**
    },
    (error) => console.log(error))
```

This part of the code subscribes to the observable. So that when the request has finished loading any code within the `subscribe()` gets executed depending on whether the request has been successful. All the code in `public onGet() {}` scope will be executed by now apart from the `.subscribe()` This will only get executed when the request has finished loading.

You will never know how long the request will take to load so using `setTimeout()` will not be useful. So it is best to let the computer let you know when the request has finished loading and that's when you use Observables